# How to get the clone count in github api

Tags: git, github, github-api

How to get GitHub clone count using api. The below api helped me to get fork count and watcher count (https://www-github.com/api/v3/repos/Community/reponame ) . but couldn't find clone count. Is it possible to get fork ,watcher and clone count from single rest api?

Comment: Shouldn't that help: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/traffic/#clones

Comment: @Jan.. thanks a lot.. i don't want breakup. just total count from beginning to as of now..  i looked at statistics api in github.. not helped me..

Comment: Well refering to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697557/is-there-a-way-to-get-download-clone-statistics-of-a-git-repository I think that maybe impossible. Didn't saw a statistic for whole clone count on github but maybe I've overseen something ;)

Comment: @Jan.. looking for option in api.. not through webui

Comment: @AhmadShakib please do not spam the edit review-queue with single-character-edits. Make sure you thoroughly address all issues with posts you edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't seem to be exposed within the API. Similar [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947625/get-github-total-clone-statistics) found.